# How can I add up the elements of a row in a 2 dimensional array Java

Tags: java, arrays, bubble-sort

Hey I'm trying to code a model for the Least Recently Used paging algorithm. I'm relatively new to Java and coding in general and I just can't find the error in my code.

I want to implement the free memory with a 2 dimensional array, and when referencing a row i change the bits in the corresponding row to 1 and in the corresponding column to 0. Then I want to add up the elements in each row and sort them using the bubblesort algorithm.

There lies my Problem: it seems I just can't get the adding up or the sorting right. I hope someone can help me because it seems no matter what I try, it doesn't work.

Here is the part of my code in question since it seems to be in stackoverflows rules that I can't post the whole code.
page [][] is the 2d array which i use to change the bytes.

I would be very grateful for any help because I'm getting demotivated slowly but surely.

```
// array for bubblesort and adding up of rows
        int sort[] = new int[page.length];
        int sumtemp = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < page.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < page[i].length; j++) {
                sumtemp += page[i][j];
                sum = sumtemp;
            }
            for (i = 0; i < page.length; i++)
                sort[i] = sum;
            sumtemp = 0;

        }

        // bubblesort
        int n1 = sort.length;
        int temp = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < (n1 - i); j++) {

                if (sort[j - 1] > sort[j]) {
                    // sort
                    temp = sort[j - 1];
                    sort[j - 1] = sort[j];
                    sort[j] = temp;

                }

            }

        }
```

My Output: it works until the last output, where the page to be deleted should be 5 not 4:

How many pages shall fit in the memory?

5

Which page do you want to reference? Please choose a number between 1 and 5. Have you finished referencing, please type in

4

0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0

1 1 1 0 1

0 0 0 0 0

Page to delete = 1

Which page do you want to reference? Please choose a number between 1 and 5.

Have you finished referencing, please type in

3

0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0

1 1 0 1 1

1 1 0 0 1

0 0 0 0 0

Page to delete = 1

Which page do you want to reference? Please choose a number between 1 and 5. 
Have you finished referencing, please type in

1

0 1 1 1 1

0 0 0 0 0

0 1 0 1 1

0 1 0 0 1

0 0 0 0 0

Page to delete = 5

Which page do you want to reference? Please choose a number between 1 and 5. 
Have you finished referencing, please type in

2

0 0 1 1 1

1 0 1 1 1

0 0 0 1 1

0 0 0 0 1

0 0 0 0 0

Page to delete = 4

Which page do you want to reference? Please choose a number between 1 and 5. Have you finished referencing, please type in

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No, I don't get any errors. I'll edit my question with the console output.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the **Bubble Sort** logic:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (n1 - i - 1); j++) {

            if (sort[j + 1] > sort[j]) { //ascending order
                // sort
                temp = sort[j + 1];
                sort[j + 1] = sort[j];
                sort[j] = temp;

            }
 }
```